# How do you create and add items to a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key

I want to loop through a list, and first check if an item exists in a dictionary, if it does I want to skip it and move on, if not, I want to add it to the appropriate level in the dictionary.

I am starting with and empty dictionary and this list of lists

```
my_dictionary = {}

file1 = ['model_a', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_a', 'filename_a']
file2 = ['model_b', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_a', 'filename_a']
file3 = ['model_a', 'part_b', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_a', 'filename_b']
file4 = ['model_c', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_a', 'filename_a']
file5 = ['model_b', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_b', 'version_a', 'filename_a']
file6 = ['model_a', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_b', 'filename_a']

file_list = [file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6]
```

I create a loop and create variables to check and write to the dictionary:

```
for item in file_list:
    model, pn, category, file_format, version, filename = item
```

My goal is this:

```
    {
         "model_a": {
             "part_a": {
                 "category_a": {
                     "format_a": {
                         "version_a": "filename_a",
                         "version_b": "filename_a"
                     }
                 }
             },
             "part_b": {
                 "category_a": {
                     "format_a": {
                         "version_a": "filename_b"
                     }
                 }
             }
         },
         "model_b": {
             "part_a": {
                 "category_a": {
                     "format_a": {
                         "version_a": "filename_a"
                     },
                     "format_b": {
                         "version_a": "filename_a"
                     }
                 }
             }
         },
         "model_c": {
             "part_a": {
                 "category_a": {
                     "format_a": {
                         "version_a": "filename_a"
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

[Tree image of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/914eh.png)

First attempt was just writing items in each loop without checking first:

```
# first attempt
for item in file_list:
    model, pn, category, file_format, version, filename = item

    my_object = {pn: {category: {file_format: {version: filename}}}}
    my_dictionary[model] = my_object
```

which makes it through the loop but overwrites items instead of adding the missing parts.

Next attempts were using try/except and step through each level of the dictionary to check for keys.  It works at the first level, and produces missing keys, and skips existing keys.

```
    try:
        my_dictionary[model]
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        model_exists = False
    else:
        model_exists = True

    if not model_exists:
        my_dictionary[model] = {pn}
```

In this step I successfully create a key = model with a value of key = pn, but when I try the same approach at the next level:

```
    try:
        my_dictionary[model][pn]
```

I get: "TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable.  I am running 3.10.1, where I though dictionaries are ordered.

I feel like this could be a solution: [Creating a nested dictionary from a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697886/creating-a-nested-dictionary-from-a-nested-list) because the posted questioned looked liek what I'm trying to do, but it honestly makes no sense to me.

Comment: `{pn}` creates a set, not a dictionary.

Comment: The question you linked to is the solution to this, you just need to repeat it for each item in your list. If it doesn't make sense there, it won't make any more sense if we repeat it here.

Comment: _but it honestly makes no sense to me_ Can you explain what, exactly, makes no sense?

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm very new to python, and programming.  The "It makes no sense" is that I have not yet encountered "collections" or "defaultdict" or "lambda."  I'll be looking into those items.  When I first viewed that post it seemed far beyond my current knowlede, and I was hoping there was a less elegant, more beginner friendly solution.  Perhaps when I start reading about those items I will be able to understand them a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `setdefault()` is your friend. The dictionary `setdefault()` method will help us initialize the required sub-dictionaries for a given key. If you have used `collections.defaultdict()` then you have the basic understanding already. Of course, a nested `defaultdict()` could also be employed here. I prefer `setdefault()` over `defaultdict()` as it leaves you with a plain old dictionary in the end.

Note, I formatted the line oddly so it is easier to read.

```py
import json

file1 = ['model_a', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_a', 'filename_a']
file2 = ['model_b', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_a', 'filename_a']
file3 = ['model_a', 'part_b', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_a', 'filename_b']
file4 = ['model_c', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_a', 'filename_a']
file5 = ['model_b', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_b', 'version_a', 'filename_a']
file6 = ['model_a', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_b', 'filename_a']
file_list = [file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6]
my_dictionary = {}
for model, pn, category, file_format, version, filename in file_list:
    my_dictionary \
        .setdefault(model, {}) \
        .setdefault(pn, {}) \
        .setdefault(category, {}) \
        .setdefault(file_format, {})[version] = filename
print(json.dumps(my_dictionary, indent=4))
```

This might also help illustrate what is happening.

```py
my_dictionary = {}
for model, pn, category, file_format, version, filename in file_list:
    target = my_dictionary.setdefault(model, {})
    target = target.setdefault(pn, {})
    target = target.setdefault(category, {})
    target = target.setdefault(file_format, {})
    target[version] = filename
```

Either formatting will give you:

```
{
    "model_a": {
        "part_a": {
            "category_a": {
                "format_a": {
                    "version_a": "filename_a",
                    "version_b": "filename_a"
                }
            }
        },
        "part_b": {
            "category_a": {
                "format_a": {
                    "version_a": "filename_b"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "model_b": {
        "part_a": {
            "category_a": {
                "format_a": {
                    "version_a": "filename_a"
                },
                "format_b": {
                    "version_a": "filename_a"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "model_c": {
        "part_a": {
            "category_a": {
                "format_a": {
                    "version_a": "filename_a"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you!  I tried what you provided and it worked, which is excellent.  I was reading about setdefault to understand why it worked.  I read a couple of articles and I need to practice using it.  The most helpful for me was your illustration of target = ... target =.  It is a perfect illustration for me on how the variables are assigned using setdefault() while looping the list.  Again, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good use-case for recursion:

```
def update_dict(dictionary, items):
    if len(items) == 2:
        dictionary[items[0]] = items[1]
    else:
        if items[0] not in dictionary:
            dictionary[items[0]] = {}
        update_dict(dictionary[items[0]], items[1:])

my_dictionary = {}

file1 = ['model_a', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_a', 'filename_a']
file2 = ['model_b', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_a', 'filename_a']
file3 = ['model_a', 'part_b', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_a', 'filename_b']
file4 = ['model_c', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_a', 'filename_a']
file5 = ['model_b', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_b', 'version_a', 'filename_a']
file6 = ['model_a', 'part_a', 'category_a', 'format_a', 'version_b', 'filename_a']

file_list = [file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6]

for file in file_list:
    update_dict(my_dictionary, file)
```

The recursive function can also be written shorter, using `setdefault`:

```
def update_dict(dictionary, items):
    if len(items) == 2:
        dictionary[items[0]] = items[1]
    else:
        update_dict(dictionary.setdefault(items[0], {}), items[1:])
```